# Unit Testing with Cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios, cocos2d, unit-testing

How to implement Unit Testing with Cocos2D framework?
What are the good practices?

Is there any testing framework like JUnit Framework at Eclipse for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using XCode, it has a testing framework called OCUnit built in.  Otherwise there are other framework options.  I would try adding a mocking framework if it is not already included by now.

This is a good start:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3716/unit-testing-in-xcode-4-quick-start-guide

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/00-About_Unit_Testing/about.html